# What does "it" refers to in this context?

Tags: sentence-construction

> Whenever democratic theory makes its normative point about equality in
> society (Dahl 1989, 323ff.), it rests mostly on a moral appeal that is
> unconvincing because of **its** essential point that democratic procedures
> by themselves have an equalising effect
>
> *- Swiss Democracy by Wolf Linder*

This sentence has three "it". The first and second one refers to "democratic theory", but I'm confised about the third one. Does it refers to "**democratic theory**" or to "**moral appeal**"?

Comment: the "moral appeal"

Answer (score 2):

> Whenever **[[** democratic theory **]]** makes **(( [[ its ]]** normative point **))** about equality in society, **(( it ))** rests mostly on **{{** a moral appeal **}}** that is unconvincing because of **{{ its }}** essential point that democratic procedures by themselves have an equalising effect

---

- ...**its** normative point about equality

  - refers to **democratic theory**

---

- ...**it** rests mostly on ...

  - refers to **the normative point** that (the) democratic theory makes

---

- ...**its** essential point that

  - refers to **a moral appeal that is unconvincing**